# Replacing images with a tabled image in a WordPress template for HTML email

Tags: php, image, wordpress

I'm creating an html email template in WordPress so that people can create their own emails using the WP system. In order to do this, I need to create all styles as inline css. I'm having trouble with the images simply because I need to replace all the images with images inside tables so that they'll be aligned correctly when sent via email clients.

The problem is, the images won't work inside the table because I can't figure out how to call them correctly.

Below is the code I'm using to replace the image with a table bound version of the image.

```
    $content = get_the_content();

apply_filters( 'the_content', $content );

$content = preg_replace( '/(<img[^>]*/>)/', '<table align="right"><tr><td>$1</td></tr></table>', $content); echo $content;
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Found the solution:  
$content = preg_replace( '/(<img[^>]*>)/', '<table align="right"><tr><td>$1</td></tr></table>', $content);

Answer (score 0):

Two issues with your preg_replace statement:

1) Your search looks for

```
<img src="image1.jpg" /
```

and stops there. You didn't include the trailing > for your image in your initial grep statement. Your search should be this:

```
'/<img[^>]*>/'
```

2) Now, wrap this up in a nice set of brackets

```
'/(<img[^>]*>)/'
```

and change your

```
'<table align="right"><tr><td>', '/<img[^>]*/', '</td></tr></table>'
```

to

```
'<table align="right"><tr><td>$1</td></tr></table>'
```

When you want to use parts of the string you just searched for, you have to wrap the selected string in brackets. This allows you access the string using a variable call in the replace statement.

In conclusion...

```
$content = preg_replace( '/(<img[^>]*>)/', '<table align="right"><tr><td>$1</td></tr></table>', $content);
```

Enjoy!